# Who draws a card from Curious Obsession?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have enchanted an opponent's creature with [Curious Obsession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCurious%20Obsession%5d), which player draws the card after damage is dealt?

Answer (score 5):

The creature's controller draws the card.

This is because Curious Obsession grants the draw ability to the creature:

> Enchanted creature [...] has “Whenever this creature deals combat damage to a player, you may draw a card.”

The “you” here refers to the controller of whatever object the ability is on (CR 109.5). The ability is on the creature, so the creature's controller will be drawing the card.

This is contrast to [Curiosity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=442041) which will cause the aura's controller to draw a card, because the ability is on the aura itself.

---

> [**109.5**](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr109/#5) The words “you” and “your” on an object refer to the object’s controller. [...] For a triggered ability, this is the controller of the object [that the ability is on] when the ability triggered, unless it’s a delayed triggered ability.

Comment: I think you are missing the most important part of the card in you answer. The important words are "and has". Simply stating "you" would refer to the enchantment's controller.

Comment: @Andrey I think I covered that in expressing that the ability was granted to the creature. I'll take that as a sign I should rephrase to make that clearer.

Comment: You did, but without quoting the text on the card that expresses that to the player, you make your answer misleading for the general case. I thought you were wrong until I reread the card.

Comment: Gotcha. Your initial comment prompted me to revise how I was quoting the card—does that look OK?